# Viewport3D not support UWP

Tags: uwp

I find Demo.StreetView in GMap project, it's good for street view, I want to change it to UWP. But it use "Viewport3D" that not suported in UWP. How can I do?
 `public class PanoramaViewer : Viewport3D`

Answer (score 1):

As you've known, `Viewport3D` is not supported in UWP. UWP apps support 3D graphics via different ways. For example, JavaScript apps support 3D graphics via **WebGL**. XAML apps support 3D graphics via **Direct3D** interop with the [**SwapChainPanel**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel) control and related classes. However, XAML UI supports [3-D perspective effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/3-d-perspective-effects) directly.

I'm not familiar with GMap project. But if you inspect on [MapControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl), you will find the map is also rendered on a `SwapChainPanel`. You may try with this to implement what you want. 
[image]

For more info, see [DirectX programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-programming) and also [XAML SwapChainPanel DirectX interop sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SwapChainPanel-00cb688b).